# Firebase Paginate

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made the code below referring to the pagination document of FIREBASE.

( https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#web-v8_3    )

I know that 'limit(3)' prints 3 documents, but I don't know how to use the 'next' and 'last' variables.

What I want to implement is to show three of my posts per page and move to the next page when the button is pressed.

Since I just started web development, everything is difficult. please help me

```js
var first = db.collection('product').orderBy('date').limit(3);

var paginate = first.get().then((snapshot)=>{
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id);
      var summary = doc.data().content.slice(0,50);
      var template = `<div class="product">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('${doc.data().image}')"></div>
        <div class="flex-grow-1 p-4">
          <h5 class="title"><a href= "/detail.html?id=${doc.id}">${doc.data().title}</a></h5>
          <p class="date">${doc.data().date.toDate()}</p>
          <p class = "summary">${summary}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>`;  
      $('.container').append(template);
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this function:

```js
let lastDocSnap = null

async function getNextPage(lastDoc) {
  let ref = db.collection('product').orderBy('date')
  
  // Check if there is previos snapshot available
  if (lastDoc) ref = ref.startAfter(lastDoc)
  const snapshot = await ref.limit(3).get()

  // Set new last snapshot
  lastDocSnapshot = snapshot.docs[snapshot.size - 1]

  // return data
  return snapshot.docs.map(d => d.data())
}
```

While calling this function, pass the lastDocSnap as a param:

```js
getNextPage().then((docs) => {
  docs.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc itself is the data of document here
    // Hence .data() is removed from original code

    console.log(doc.id);
    var summary = doc.content.slice(0,50);
    var template = `<div class="product">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('${doc.image}')"></div>
        <div class="flex-grow-1 p-4">
          <h5 class="title"><a href= "/detail.html?id=${doc.id}">${doc.title}</a></h5>
          <p class="date">${doc.date.toDate()}</p>
          <p class = "summary">${summary}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>`;  
      $('.container').append(template);
  })
})
```

Call this function at page load (as `lastDocSnap` will be `null`, it'll fetch first 3 docs). Call the same function when user clicks 'next' but this time as we have `lastDocSnap`, the `startAfter` method will be added to the query. This essentially means the query will first order the document by date and then fetch 3 documents *after* the document you pass in `startAfter`

Comment: Thank you friend,
I put a function in the button and run it, but the same 3 documents appear again.
please help me

Comment: @egwang can you please share your complete updated code ?

Comment: @egwang You are not passing the lastDoc snap as I mentioned in my answer. `$('#aa').click(()=>{
    getNextPage(lastDocSnap) //<--`

Comment: @egwang as I said just pass that parameter. `getNextPage(lastDocSnap)` wherever you are calling `lastDocSnap`. on page load as well as on next button click